# Syntax error on Join Operation - sql view in access 2013

Tags: ms-access, join, ms-access-2010, sql-view

I'm trying to do some complicated joins in the sql view in access and it's really hard to know why I'm getting errors. I'm more proficient in using SQL joins in SQL itself and the SQL view of access really is confusing when giving errors. I have no idea what I need to do to fix this error. Please see below.

```
SELECT Table1.PAT_NAME AS PATNM, 
       Table1.PAT_MRN_ID AS MRN, 
       Table2.Start_Date AS StartDT, 
       Table2.END_date AS ENDDT, 
       Table2.episode_ID AS EPSDID, 
       Table2.POS_NAME AS POS, 
       Table3.READMITDT AS READMITD
FROM Table2 
    LEFT JOIN ( Table1 ON Table2.PAT_MRN_ID = Table1.PAT_MRN_ID)
    JOIN (Table3 ON Table1.PAT_ID = Table3.PATIDR AND
         ( Table3.READMITDT <= dateadd("d", 1, isnull(Table2.END_DATE,NOW())
          OR Table3.READMITDT < dateadd("d", 30, Table2.START_DATE))
          AND Table3.READMITDT >= Table2.start_date))
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is one problem ...

```sql
JOIN (Table3 ON Table1.PAT_ID = Table3.PATIDR
^^^^
```

Access SQL does not accept `JOIN` alone.  You must always specify the type of join you want: `INNER JOIN`; `LEFT JOIN`; or `RIGHT JOIN`.

Use the query designer's Design View (instead of SQL View) to set up your joins.  The query designer knows about the syntax rules which keep the db engine happy.  Later, you can switch back to SQL View to see how your valid joins are represented there.

Access SQL recognizes `LEFT OUTER JOIN` as a synonym for `LEFT JOIN`, and `RIGHT OUTER JOIN` for `RIGHT JOIN`.  When you edit the query in the query designer, it will likely discard `OUTER`, but you can add it back without breaking a working query.

Consider moving those `DateAdd` conditions to your query's `WHERE` clause.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I do use query designer first. I must have just omitted the join types when I was modifying for the example, but thats good to know.. I didn't know that. It just gets complicated after I stray away from the query designer. The parenthesis locations are always confusing.. I did end up putting dateadd in my where clause and that seemed to make things less confusing. thanks! I went back to query designer several times and added phrases back in one at a time until I figured it out.. This one took me a good portion of the day to get right!

Answer (score 1):

```
it is better to use WHERE Clause after join operation. remove 'and'

JOIN Table3 ON (Table1.PAT_ID = Table3.PATIDR) AND
      (Table3.READMITDT <= dateadd("d", 1, isnull(Table2.END_DATE,NOW())
      OR Table3.READMITDT < dateadd("d", 30, Table2.START_DATE) 
      AND Table3.READMITDT >= Table2.start_date))

should be


JOIN Table3 ON (Table1.PAT_ID = Table3.PATIDR) 
WHERE
      (Table3.READMITDT <= dateadd("d", 1, isnull(Table2.END_DATE,NOW())
      OR Table3.READMITDT < dateadd("d", 30, Table2.START_DATE) 
      AND Table3.READMITDT >= Table2.start_date))
```

Comment: I figured it out now. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0):

I am not familier with ms access sql. but I think LEFT JOIN should be LEFT OUTER JOIN and your brackets  are wrong. after Join bracket should be open after tables before ON clause
look following example

FROM Table2 LEFT JOIN ( Table1 ON Table2.PAT_MRN_ID = Table1.PAT_MRN_ID) should be change as
FROM Table2 LEFT **OUTER** JOIN  Table1 ON (Table2.PAT_MRN_ID = Table1.PAT_MRN_ID)

Comment: Thank you, I made the changes, but now it is telling me I have a missing operator and gives the entire from statement, so hard to tell where the missing operator is.

Comment: it is better to use WHERE Clause after join operation. remove 'and'

JOIN Table3 ON (Table1.PAT_ID = Table3.PATIDR) AND
      (Table3.READMITDT <= dateadd("d", 1, isnull(Table2.END_DATE,NOW())
      OR Table3.READMITDT < dateadd("d", 30, Table2.START_DATE) 
      AND Table3.READMITDT >= Table2.start_date))

should be


JOIN Table3 ON (Table1.PAT_ID = Table3.PATIDR) 

**WHERE**
      (Table3.READMITDT <= dateadd("d", 1, isnull(Table2.END_DATE,NOW())
      OR Table3.READMITDT < dateadd("d", 30, Table2.START_DATE) 
      AND Table3.READMITDT >= Table2.start_date))

Answer (score 0):

I ran it through a syntax checker https://sql.treasuredata.com/. This version gives no syntax error.

```
SELECT
  Table1.PAT_NAME AS PATNM
 ,Table1.PAT_MRN_ID AS MRN
 ,Table2.Start_Date AS StartDT
 ,Table2.END_date AS ENDDT
 ,Table2.episode_ID AS EPSDID
 ,Table2.POS_NAME AS POS
 ,Table3.READMITDT AS READMITD
FROM
  Table2
  LEFT OUTER JOIN Table1 ON (Table2.PAT_MRN_ID = Table1.PAT_MRN_ID)
  JOIN Table3 ON (Table1.PAT_ID = Table3.PATIDR) AND
      (Table3.READMITDT <= dateadd("d", 1, isnull(Table2.END_DATE,NOW())
      OR Table3.READMITDT < dateadd("d", 30, Table2.START_DATE) 
      AND Table3.READMITDT >= Table2.start_date))
```

Comment: Thanks - I tried both and still getting syntax error in From clause. I like leaving it as a where statement though if it gives me the same results as I have in SQL.  Also, I have to leave that extra parenthesis around the two statements with OR because that is part of the bigger AND statement. It needs to be just OR of those two. Here is where I'm at    JOIN Table3 ON (Table1.PAT_ID = Table3.PATIDR) WHERE
      (Table3.READMITDT <= dateadd("d", 1, isnull(Table2.END_DATE,NOW())
      OR Table3.READMITDT < dateadd("d", 30, Table2.START_DATE) )
      AND Table3.READMITDT >= Table2.start_date

Comment: Sorry for the code above.. Here is the example again                      JOIN Table3 ON (Table1.PAT_ID = Table3.PATIDR) 
WHERE
      (Table3.READMITDT <= dateadd("d", 1, isnull(Table2.END_DATE,NOW())
      OR Table3.READMITDT < dateadd("d", 30, Table2.START_DATE)) 
      AND Table3.READMITDT >= Table2.start_date